# Setting a protocol based theme in a View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I managed to get protocol-based theming working based on this: https://basememara.com/protocol-oriented-themes-for-ios-apps/

However, while setting `theme.apply(for: application)` in AppDelegate works, using the same as `theme.apply(for: UIApplication)` inside a View Controller throws a error: Cannot convert value of type 'UIApplication.Type' to expected argument type 'UIApplication'

What’s going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `theme.apply(for: application)` you pass an instance of UIApplication as argument.
In `theme.apply(for: UIApplication)` you pass UIApplication as type and it causes error because function expects instance of UIApplication to be passed.
Try to pass UIApplication.shared instead. Like this:

```
theme.apply(for: UIApplication.shared)
```

It should help.